# ¿Como se forma el sustantivo '-ción' relacionado con "asumir"?

Tags: verbos, tiempos-verbales

No supe como plantear el título de la pregunta, ya que no se su nombre en particular, pero por ejemplo el verbo *terminar* puede usarse como *terminación* o *conocer* como *cognición*.
Para *asumir* pensaba en *asumción*, pero haciendo un googleo rápido no encontré mucho, más bien de gente que al parecer trataba de escribir "Asunción", como la capital de Paraguay, ¿o quizás ésta es la forma correcta?.
¿Alguna idea de como se escribe? ¿Y como se llama este tipo de conjugación o terminación de verbo?

Comment: Efectivamente, [_terminación_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZYkIonL) es la acción y efecto de _terminar_, luego [_asunción_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=47cllX1) es la accíon y efecto de _asumir_. No es conjugación (_acción y efecto de..._ :D) porque ya no es verbo sino nombre, pero no sé cómo se llama el concepto. Añado: [_-ción_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9I27Gyi) explica _Forma sustantivos deverbales que expresan acción y efecto_.

Comment: No creo que estas palabras sigan alguna regla fija. Creo que el sustantivo podría derivar del adjetivo *asumible* y quedar como **asumibilidad**.

Comment: @fedorqui "sustantivación" o "nominalización".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En efecto, la forma de designar la acción o efecto de asumir es *asunción*, no *asumción* ya que por regla general cuando corresponde una *m* en final de sílaba, la misma se transforma en *n* a menos que siga una consonante labial (de la misma manera, de la Virgen María se dice que fue *asunta* al cielo).

Hay algo curioso y es que *[asumir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=47S4L2q)* se suele usar equivocadamente con el significado de "[presumir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=U7YygFe)", es decir "suponer" o "dar por seguro", como en

> *Asumo que actúa de buena fe.*
>   *Usted asumió que yo estaba de acuerdo.*

En ese caso, aunque el verbo sea aceptado, para el sustantivo no se utiliza *asunción* sino *presunción*.

> *Debemos respetar la presunción de inocencia.*

Otra palabra que se nominaliza de esta manera (cambiando *-mir* por *-nción*) es *consunción*, pero sólo con su significado pasivo (la acción de consumirse o enflaquecer).

Comment: Una respuesta completa, que aclara *todo*.